# How to define a type that extends from an abstract class but is never the toplevel abstract class?

Tags: typescript

Given the following how should you define type`someTypeThatIncludeDecendantsOfA_ButNotA`?

```
abstract class A {}; 
class B extends A {
    constructor(){
        console.log("Creating B")
        super()
    }
 };

 class C extends A{};

 const myMap = new Map<string, someTypeThatIncludeDecendantsOfA_ButNotA>([ 
     ["B", B],
     ["C", C]
 ]);

 const Constructor = myMap.get("B");

 const obj = new Constructor();
```

I've tried defining the map as `new Map<string, typeof A>()` but then I get an error saying `Cannot create an instance of an abstract class`. Which makes sense.

Also played around with `Exclude` and `Extract` types. But that also turned up nothing useful. I think Java uses the syntax `new Map<string, ? extends A>`.
I've been pouring over the documentation but can't seem to find anything similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a constructor signature instead of the actual class:

```
const myMap = new Map<string, new () => A>([ 
    ["B", B],
    ["C", C]
]);

const Constructor = myMap.get("B");

const obj = new Constructor();
```

The type `new () => A` represents a constructor (because of the `new` keyword) with an empty argument list (`()`) that returns an instance of `A`. Any derived concrete class that has an default constructor will satisfy this signature.

Comment: Thanks, didn't even think of that. I use `new () => A`.

Answer (score -1):

you can create an interface and implement your class `A` from that interface, and define your `typesomeTypeThatIncludeDecendantsOfA_ButNotA` type as your interface

```
interface AA { .... }

abstract class A implements AA {}; 
class B extends A {
    constructor(){
        console.log("Creating B")
        super()
    }
 };

 class C extends A{};

 const myMap = new Map<string, AA>([ 
     ["B", B],
     ["C", C]
 ]);

 const Constructor = myMap.get("B");

 const obj = new Constructor();
```